# calculating a value between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find a value inside an array.

my function:

`$discount_quantity = $Products->getProductsDiscountQuantity($products_id)` return this :

```
[0] => string(1) "1" [1] => string(1) "5" [2] => string(2) "10"
```

I have a quantity for example `$qty = 6` and I need to applied a discount on that

```
if $qty < 5 then $discount = 0%
if $qty > 5 et qty < 10 then $discount = 10%
if $qty > 10 then $discount = 15%
```

How to make with an array ?

Comment: is $discount_quantity an array like [0] => string(1) "1" [1] => string(1) "5" [2] => string(2) "10"   ?

Comment: yes, if I understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$discount_quantity = array( "1", "5", "10");

foreach($discount_quantity as $k => $v)
{
  if($v < 5)
  {
    $v = $v;
  }
  elseif($v >= 5 && $v < 10)
  {
    $v = $v - ($v * 10 / 100);
  }
  elseif($v >= 10)
  {
    $v = $v - ($v * 15 / 100);
  }
  $discount_quantity[$k] = $v;
}

print_r($discount_quantity);

?>;
```

Output: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4.5 [2] => 8.5 ) ;